# reading a string of numbers as words then printing each word as a number

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to write a code which takes an input from 0 to any positive integer, that will return a string of 0 for when zero is entered, 10 when 1 is entered, 1110 for when 2 is entered, 3110 for when 3 is entered and so on, this is saying that when input 0 occurs output is 0, then when 1 is input it looks at the input for 0 and reads it as 'one zero' and prints 10, the for 2 reads input 1 as 'one one and one zero' and prints 1110, and so on and so forth. I have an idea of what to do but it's too vague to translate into code. When I posted this I didn't know what it was called but since then I found that it was the look and see sequence, and my issue is that I can't use iteration, nor can I use the built-in len() or string.append() function.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia article on this sequence - [Look-and-say sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use any iteration, then you need to use recursion with a stop at 0. It will look something like this:

```
def whatever(input):
    """
    >>> whatever(0)
    '0'
    >>> whatever(1)
    '10'
    >>> whatever(2)
    '1110'
    >>> whatever(3)
    '3110'
    >>> whatever(4)
    '132110'
    >>> whatever(5)
    '1113122110'
    """
    def looksay(input, result):
        if not input:
            return result
        else:
            left, right = input[0], input[1:]
            if not result:
                result = '1' + left
            else:
                left_result, count, right_result = result[:-2], int(result[-2]), result[-1]
                if left == right_result:
                    result = left_result + str(count + 1) + right_result
                else:
                    result = result + '1' + left
            return looksay(right, result)
    def helper(number, result):
        if number == 0:
            return result
        else:
            return helper(number - 1, looksay(result, ''))
    return helper(input, '0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: yes that is how the program should work and if 4 was entered '132110' should be the output

Comment: It is not the latter it would be
whatever(0) gives '0'
whatever(1) gives '10'
whatever(2) gives '1110'
whatever(3) gives '3110

Comment: Okay, but your example for 4 does not follow the pattern I have given you. The way I am suggesting, 4 would be '100' and you would translate to 'one-1, two-0s' and write '1120'. I strongly recommend you write your code with a unit test (in the pattern I have sketched for you) and post it so that others can make out your intentions.

Comment: This is a look-and-say sequence, my initial problem is that I didn't know it had a name that could be used to classify it as such, the other problem is that I can't use iteration, len(), or .append() to write this code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured out what you intend to do here. Here's a possible solution:

```
import collections

def string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    # We're going to count the digits in the previous number
    previous = string(n - 1)

    # This creates a dictionary with the number of occurences of each digit
    current = collections.Counter(previous)

    # Now format it as desired:
    return ''.join(['{}{}'.format(c, d)
                    for d, c in sorted(current.items(), reverse=True)])

print(string(4))
# prints 132110
```

@DSM, correctly pointed out below there's an other interpretation that reads out the digits of the previous number in order. Here's a way to do that:

```
def string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'

    result = []
    # We're going to iterate over the previous number's digits.
    # The loop will transform '3110' to ['3', '11', '0'].
    for digit in string(n - 1):
        # If it's the first char, just add it to the list
        if not result:
            result.append(digit)
        # If the current digit is the same as the last one, add it to the 
        # last element of the list
        elif digit == result[-1][0]:
            result[-1] += digit
        # If it's a different digit, add it to the end of the list.
        else:
            result.append(digit)

    # Now format the resulting list and return it.
    return ''.join(['{}{}'.format(len(digits), digits[0])
                    for digits in result])

print(string(4))
# prints 132110
```

Comment: I interpreted it differently, as a look-and-say sequence, so that f(5) would be "1113122110", not '13123110' -- namely, you simply read f(4) left to right, and say "one one [followed by] one three [followed by] one two [followed by] two ones [followed by] one zero".

Comment: Hmm, @DSM, that's definitely a possible interpretation too. It seems that both our interpretations are equal for the first four examples. The problem is that's the only examples he gave.

Comment: Well, if we're giving the game away :-), my code was def f(n): return '0' if n == 0 else ''.join((str(len(list(ger)))+c) for c,ger in itertools.groupby(f(n-1))).

Comment: That's quite, emm, how do I put this, short? ;) `groupby` is much better than my mess.

Comment: this is a look and say sequence yet for this portion I can't use iteration nor can I use the built in len() function, which is actually why I'm stumped, I should have put that into the question.

Comment: now I know I can switch the .append() to += but out of curiosity, how would I switch this for loop to a form of recursion only, also in the 'elif' statement what does result[-1][0] mean exactly.

Comment: Also I cannot use lists, basically my professor just tried to make it the as hard as he could to write this